# Why is FIDE investigating Karjakin and Shipov, but not Karpov?

Tags: fide, karpov

Recently FIDE decided to [refer GMs Karjakin and Shipov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39375/what-rule-is-fides-ethics-and-disciplinary-commission-investigating-karjakin-an) to the ethics and disciplinary commission for supporting the Russian invasion of Ukraine. They have not, however, decided to refer GM Anatoly Karpov, even though Karpov is a member of the Russian parliament and voted to recognize the independence of the Donetsk and Luhansk People's Republics.. Why?

Comment: "... *voted to recognize the independence of the* ..."  **Citation needed**. I don't think our mod's edit is harmful, but this should probably carry some citations.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan The vote can be seen on Duma's website, but I currently cannot access it. It used to be here: http://vote.duma.gov.ru/vote/117112

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is a different quality in how these players expressed themselves in public.**

Both Karjakin and Shipov uttered statements in favour of the war and in support of Russia. FIDE ultimately decided to suspend Karjakin (and this suggests the reasons they investigated these players in the first place):

In a [ten-page document](https://www.fide.com/docs/decisions-resolutions/FIDE%20EDC%20Decision%20case%202%202022.pdf), the commission gives reasons for its decision. Among other things, the officials explain that the **publicity of statements** is a factor in the decision. The statements of the world-class player Karjakin would have **triggered a considerable number of reactions**, while Shipov was far less visible. The Commission states that Sergey Karjakin's **statements have damaged the reputation of chess and FIDE**.

Karpov, on the other hand, has done nothing of this kind. His vote in the Duma cannot be seen as a personal public statement in favour of war comparable to that of Karjakin or Shipov. He is subjected to constraints in Russia, e.g. because of his party membership and the political situation in Russia, i.e. "disadvantages" for dissenters. He is a follower rather than an enthusiast warmonger like Karjakin.
In Russia, the opinion that the invasion was right, is common. Karpov, a Russian, most likely shares this opinion, but political opinions are not sanctioned by FIDE.
There is also no "kinship detention" for Russians in general, even though [prominent players](https://en.newizv.ru/news/2023-02-07/magnus-carlsen-opposed-the-participation-of-russian-chess-players-in-the-tournaments-396451) increasingly approve of such ideas.
Karpov voted in his function as a member of the Duma and did not harm the reputation of chess or the FIDE and did not use his visibility as a prominent chess player to promote war.

Answer (score 18):

Karjakin is an active super-gm who has played Carlsen for the world championships and was involved in the current candidates cycle. Karpov no longer plays serious chess at the top level. To call it exhibition chess would be going too far but it is approaching that. If you look at his [recent playing record](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4100026/calculations) at standard play it is mostly the occasional Bundesliga appearance. Those invitations are unlikely to be repeated any time soon.

What FIDE are looking to do is to strip him of honorary FIDE titles. According to their updated "[Official Statement](https://fide.com/news/1603)":

> After receiving the opinion of Mr Rivello, the Chair of FIDE Constitutional Commission, the **FIDE Council decides to suspend the title of the FIDE Ambassador for Life for Anatoly Karpov** and asks the General Assembly to take a decision on the matter. The **FIDE Council also approves that sanctioned persons would be denied to hold any honorary or official positions in FIDE and would not be invited to any official FIDE events**. Both decisions have been taken by the majority of votes.

Comment: Shipov is also inactive right? https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4113624/calculations

Comment: @Allure He is much less active than Karpov but about 20 years younger so could conceivably play serious chess again. I also wondered why Shipov was selected. Karjakin makes sense because he is a candidate. Shipov is mainly known for writing books afaik.

Comment: @Allure: Shipov and Karjakin (or someone using the accounts associated with them) have been active on social media (Facebook and Twitter, respectively) spreading Russian propaganda (and in my opinion, misinformation). To my knowledge, Karpov is not active on social media. (Also, he might not have had a real choice about his vote in the Duma.)

Comment: @Brian Towers
He is known as the №1 Russian commentator/streamer, but as a book author.